# How can I get the Facebook object id for a new web page?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I've got an Android app that integrates the Facebook Android SDK.  We'd like to set it up so, at the users request, it dynamically creates a webpage and sends a "like" to Facebook for that page.

However, in order to do this it seems we need a Facebook Object ID for the webpage, and the page won't get a Facebook Object ID until someone physically loads the page and clicks the like button in the Javascript.

How can we get Facebook to assign an object ID for our page when it gets created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the webpage id by posting to the graph using ?id= url.

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://shawnsspace.com/plugins/

SEE: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#reading selection, then ?ids=