# Is there a service or way to get the same information as the Facebook Object Debugger page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are creating a project where I have a list of URLs and I would like to display some info about each page just like Facebook does when you add a link to a post.

Is there a service or API call that returns me a JSON of the graph properties just like the one generated at the bottom of the [Facebook Object Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object) ? (ex: http://graph.facebook.com/421751811580 )

The [reading graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#reading) states that I can pass in a URL as an id. However, for some URLs it doesn't return all the data as the Debug Tool. (ex: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.terra.com.br)

My other idea is to call the Object Debugger with a URL and parse the page. But I´m not sure if that is a safe or allowed by Facebook. (ex: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.terra.com.br)

This is the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210721/how-can-i-get-the-facebook-object-id-for-a-new-web-page) that led me to the *?ids=* information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE [Nov 6, 2014]**: Sadly, adding `format=json` has no effect with the current version of Facebook OG debugger.

Add &format=json to your call.  I'd be wary about making a lot of calls to this, just because it is not part of the official API.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.terra.com.br&format=json

```
{
   "warning":[
      {
         "type":"Inferred Property",
         "message":"The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags."
      },
      {
         "type":"Inferred Property",
         "message":"The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags."
      },
      {
         "type":"Inferred Property",
         "message":"The og:image property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags."
      },
      {
         "type":"Inferred Property",
         "message":"The og:locale property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags."
      }
   ],
   "info":[
      {
         "type":"fb:admins",
         "message":[
            1640032884
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"og:url",
         "message":"http:\/\/www.terra.com.br\/portal\/"
      },
      {
         "type":"og:type",
         "message":"website"
      },
      {
         "type":"og:title",
         "message":"Terra - Not\u00edcias, v\u00eddeos, esportes, economia, divers\u00e3o, m\u00fasica, moda, fotolog, blog, chat"
      },
      {
         "type":"og:image",
         "message":[
            "http:\/\/p2.trrsf.com.br\/image\/get?o=cf&w=89&h=67&src=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fp2.trrsf.com.br\u00252Fimage\u00252Ffget\u00252Fcf\u00252F300\u00252F300\u00252Fimg.terra.com.br\u00252Fi\u00252F2012\u00252F01\u00252F12\u00252F2176927-3276-rec.JPG"
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"og:updated_time",
         "message":1326392389
      }
   ],
   "debug":[
      {
         "type":"Meta Tag",
         "message":"\u003cmeta property=\"fb:admins\" content=\"1640032884\" \/>"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Such a simple solution, thanks! I tried a few extra parameters, but `format` never occurred to me. This is exactly what I wanted. Any suggestions on how to discover the limits of this call, such as the the number of requests per hour/day?

Comment: No way to discover a limit I know of, other than trying making a large number of calls and seeing when it gets blocked.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be true anymore. When I test your link, it only returns the "warning" part and not the "info".

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore - returns the normal HTML response.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while, but I've gotten some recent questions about this funcioanlity. In our project we ended up using http://embed.ly/.

It isn't as complete as Facebook, but it gave us enough information to complete with satisfactory results.